# PHP loop array and iconv each item

Tags: php, arrays

Want to use iconv() on each item in an array and store them to a different array, then reassign the new array to the old one. Is this the correct way to do it?

```
foreach($partinfo as $key=>$item) {
  $p[$key] = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT', $item);
}
$partinfo = $p;
```

Comment: Looks ok. Add init for `$p` variable: `$p = array();`. Just run and test.

Comment: You can use [foreach with references](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to make this easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a string's encoding by using `mb_detect_encoding`:

```
mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', true);
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

After your loop, just write another test loop that goes through and echoes out the return value and see for yourself.